# Aggregating and displaying facebook and twitter status updates on Coldfusion Page

Tags: facebook, coldfusion, twitter

As an experiment I'd like to set up a coldfusion page that will pull and display the status updates from my own facebook account and twitter accounts that fall within an input date range; similar to tools like

http://orsiso.com/

http://www.threadsy.com/

and http://www.davidcramer.net/lifestream

I assume this will involve working with the facebook and twitter apis, which I have some experience with when working with mobile apps; but I've never tried to do something like this with a coldfusion page before.  Eventually I'd like to pull other things like images and such, but for a first test just status updates is fine.  Does anyone have sample code and/or pointers that could assist me in this endeavor?  Thank you very much in advance.

Edit: I'm interested in a variant of this idea involving a database, and I've opened up a new question regarding such:  [Pulling facebook and twitter status updates into a SQL database via Coldfusion Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495719/pulling-facebook-and-twitter-status-updates-into-a-sql-database-via-coldfusion-pa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition, you should check out [RIAForge](http://www.riaforge.org), which has CF code to handle both [Twitter](http://www.riaforge.org/index.cfm?event=page.search#twitter_catid=1) and [Facebook](http://www.riaforge.org/index.cfm?event=page.search#facebook_catid=1) APIs.

Comment: Thanks this looks interesting.  I;'m assuming your referring to:
http://cftwitterlib.riaforge.org/
and
http://cffacebook.riaforge.org/

Comment: I notice that the twitter one is a year old and the facebook one is two years old; does that make them obsolete (with the changes to oAuth and the new Open Graph API, etc)?

Comment: A good question, but you can always choose from one of the other APIs that might see more activity (the links I posted are searches on RIAForge; there are multiple hits for each social network).

Answer (score 2):

For Twitter see this..
http://www.stephenwithington.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/3/4/Use-ColdFusions-CFFeed-to-Display-Your-Twitter-Tweets-and-more-on-Your-Blog-in-30-Seconds

Comment: Thanks this definitely seems to be part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this coldfusion wrapper for the twitter API [here](http://www.mattgifford.co.uk/monkehtweets-coldfusion-twitter-cfc/), really easy to set up and grab the data from your twitter feed.

I also use the twitter4j library to access my twitter account on my coldfusion site, I followed the tutorial [here](http://blog.robobrien.com/integrating-twitter-and-oauth-with-coldfusion/) to get started.

Comment: Yeah, I also use the twitter4j java class. Highly recommended.

Comment: K, checking those out as well.